# How can I convert a big C project to VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**I'm manually re-writing the code.**

I have a big C program with 50+ .c files and 20+ .h files

I need to convert them to a class so I can run multiple instances in a single exe

I have no experience of converting C project to C++.Is there a guidance to follow?

I have done some small research with Google and have following plan:

1. mv c to cpp and compile, fix all implicit converation to explict converation
2. remove all static keyword(for file scope), resolve global name conflicts
3. create a global h file for class hearder (class FOO), move all functions and variables defination to the class as members
4. for the macros and consts defined in other h files, include with extern "C" keyword
5. rename all function in cpp files to FOO::function

Comment: C++ is not magic, and won't suddenly allow you to run multiple instances. Besides, this would make for quite unmaintainable code.

Comment: @MSalters I'm not asking for a script or something to do it for me, I'm manually re-writing it. I just looking for something in general.

Comment: Definitely don't forget to utilize RAII, smart pointers to manage resources.

Comment: Also avoid all void* in your code, use correct types or templates for generic computing

Comment: @MuratKarakuş Thanks, void * is not passing the compile, VC++ seem to be very strict

Comment: Not sth special for VC++, it is enforced by C++. Any decent compiler will do that.

Comment: VC++ compiles C source files just fine (aside from some standards compliance issues). Unless you are planning on making a lot of changes to it and don't want to work in C, why not just keep it as a C project?

Comment: Btw, before doing conversion, write some regression/unit tests with C version of application, after that do the conversion. In this way, you can verify that you didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş I wish there were some testcase, but it's a gui project, I just have to hope everything can be show again on screen:)

Comment: Same thing, you can write crude regression test for it. Run application, take screenshots and compare screenshots with python. If you can automate actions, you can save screenshot of app after each action. This would be a reasonable regression test for a gui applicaiton.

Comment: @Ferruccio I have a wxWidgets GUI framework, and the C program use native Win32 API, I could not static link the C and C++ object together, I need to convert the C project to a C++ component. (IPC is not good since I have done a version in this way, the reason is in comments of Jim's answer)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your plan is to converting 50 files into a single C++ class and instantiate multiple instances of the class. This is, at best, a severe misuse of C++ classes.  In practice, it's unlikely that this will work because you will still only have one thread of execution. Only one of those objects can run at a time. Every time you do an I/O operation (for example), everything comes to a halt until the I/O operation finishes.

I know nothing about your particular case, but in general, if I were approaching this problem, I would keep my existing code run multiple processes instead. I'd also write a shim class that managed communication with those processes using Inter-Process Communication (IPC), such as UNIX sockets or named pipes.

If you still feel that multiple instance is the way to go, then carve out a tiny fraction of your current source code and port it over so that you can understand the issues.

Comment: the IPC version was the first generation of the program, and I use set parent to embed the C GUI to C++ GUI, however, according to MSDN, setting parent to other procss is illegal(worrying about compatibility probem in new windows). The other drawback, is if the child process got focus, the outer gui lost focus and the title bar chanded to background mode, and you could not click the child GUI to bring it to front.

Comment: Add the C program to my C++ program is not causing performace issue, as it's using winapi call back, running multiple instance is just like you are adding more win32 control boxes in GUI, it's not causing performance issue.